# Spring Async task on Wildfly 8.2

Tags: spring, wildfly-8

I was trying to implement a asynchronous method on my service using @Async and returning ListenableFuture and the controller method returning a @ResponseBody Callable, I have a thread pool as bean configured to Async Support for Spring . It is running like a charm on Tomcat 8.0.15, on Wildfly, the service method is executed on controller method but the controller never returns on the web page the container just returns "Service Unavailable" . I tried to remove "ee" module at Jboss structure deployment descriptor but then the WAR wasn't deployed. Anyone have some tips to make this work?

**EDIT**

Log don't output nothing wrong.

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"search/{query}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Callable<GithubResult> printResult(@PathVariable String query) {
        Assert.notNull(query, "Query must be not null");
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<GithubResult>> result = githubLookupService.lookup(query);
        return () -> result.get().getBody();
    }
```

The Service:

```
    @Async
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<GithubResult>> lookup(String query) {
        Assert.notNull(query,"Query must be not null");
        String url = String.format("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=%s+language:java", query);
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<GithubResult>> reponseFuture = asyncTemplate
                .getForEntity(url, GithubResult.class);
        try {
            return new AsyncResult<>(reponseFuture.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException  e) {
            log.error("Cannot retrieve the response entitiy");
            return reponseFuture;
        }
    }
```

And the Spring configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="scheduler" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="50"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="20"/>
    <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="schedulerFacotryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: hard to comment without looking into config / code / logs. Please post relevant pieces.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Added the source code, there none wildfly configuration it's all in default for standalone mode